# Convert json data in simple form - Laravel chat-inbox

Tags: arrays, json, laravel, api, eloquent

I am trying to get latest messages from table 'messages' for inbox
The chat is between user and owner of the item (listed on my portal)
I want to get unique data with item_id

My code is

```
public function inbox()
{
    // $inbox = ChatMessage::distinct('item_id')->where('incoming_msg_id', auth()->user()->id)->orWhere('outgoing_msg_id', auth()->user()->id)->orderBy('msg_id', 'DESC')->get();


    $inbox = Message::where('incoming_msg_id', auth()->user()->id)->orWhere('outgoing_msg_id', auth()->user()->id)->latest('msg_id')->get()->unique('item_id');


    return $this->sendResponse($inbox,'Chat');
}
```

Result is perfect just i need is non-associative/non-object array.

Current output

```
{
"success": true,
    "data": {
        "0": {
            "msg_id": 68,
            "incoming_msg_id": 0,
            "outgoing_msg_id": 2,
            "msg": "ok let me check",
            "msg_for": "hadiya",
            "item_id": "13",
            "msg_at": "1 day ago"
        },
        "1": {
            "msg_id": 62,
            "incoming_msg_id": 0,
            "outgoing_msg_id": 2,
            "msg": "test msg",
            "msg_for": "hadiya",
            "item_id": "1",
            "msg_at": "2 days ago"
        }
    },
    "message": "Chat"
}
```

Expected Output

```
{
"success": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "msg_id": 68,
            "incoming_msg_id": 0,
            "outgoing_msg_id": 2,
            "msg": "ok let me check",
            "msg_for": "hadiya",
            "item_id": "13",
            "msg_at": "1 day ago"
        },
        {
            "msg_id": 62,
            "incoming_msg_id": 0,
            "outgoing_msg_id": 2,
            "msg": "test msg",
            "msg_for": "hadiya",
            "item_id": "1",
            "msg_at": "2 days ago"
        }
    ],
    "message": "Chat"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution after lots of revisions.
I got the distinct data in the best json format I was looking for...

```
$inbox = ChatMessage::select('msg_id','incoming_msg_id','outgoing_msg_id','msg','msg_for','item_id','msg_at')->groupBy('item_id')->where('incoming_msg_id', auth()->user()->id)->orWhere('outgoing_msg_id', auth()->user()->id)->get();
        return $this->sendResponse($inbox,'Inbox');
```

Explanation : In Laravel 8 there is a function known as `groupBy()` which is use for getting distinct results.
Check the [link here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#grouping) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple by following approach you can set the http status code also (optional).

```
return response()->json(['chat' => $inbox], 200);
```

Comment: return $this->sendResponse($inbox,'Chat'); is already sending the same data as you provided, I need expected output given my question.

Comment: Iterate the data array and store it into a new array, return this new array,maybe this approach will help you